# PFQueryCollectionView not updating upon pulling to refresh

Tags: parse-platform

Here's my current dilemma. My app allows the user to take a picture and upload it on to parse. I have a separate tab that shows all the photos taken in a `PFQueryCollectionViewController`.

The recent photos I've took does not show up in the collection view, even when I pull down to refresh. The new image is indeed uploaded in the Parse database.

Oddly enough, completely stopping the app and restarting will show the image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to insert `self.loadObjects()` into your `viewDidAppear` function. But it can cause error if you load object right before this, because app will try to load object which is being processed by parse server. Simplest solution is to add small delay.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    delay(0.4){
        self.loadObjects()
    }
}

func delay(delay:Double, closure:()->()) {
    dispatch_after(
        dispatch_time(
            DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            Int64(delay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC))
        ),
        dispatch_get_main_queue(), closure)
}
```